# what input does bytes32 take for this logic?? I've tried different string data types like the word "blue".. i also tried number types..nothing works!

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Ballot {

  struct Voter {
    uint weight;
    bool voted;
    address delegate;
    uint vote;
  }

  struct Proposal {
    bytes32 name;
    uint voteCount;
  }

  address public chairperson; 

  mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

  Proposal[] public proposals;

  constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) {
    chairperson = msg.sender;
    voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

    for(uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
      proposals.push(Proposal({name: proposalNames[i], voteCount: 0}));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass to smart contract `constructor` the type bytes32[] you should to give it this statement:

```
["bytes32","bytes32","bytes32",...]
```

For generate a bytes32 you can use this [tool](https://web3-type-converter.onbrn.com/). You put string into the first textbox, choose `bytes32/hex` type from dropdown and then you must to copy the result generated in the second textbox. Now, you add  '0' until the length of this bytes32 generate is 64 without counting the '0x' characters. At this point, you can use the statement that I declared previously and put into it your bytes32 value.
Example:

string = **blue**

bytes32 = **0x626c756500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**

Constructor input:

*["0x626c756500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]*